# Upload zip file to spring rest controller using angular 4

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, spring-rest

I want to upload .zip file to server (spring rest controller) from angular 4.
Please suggest how to do so?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some learning, i have found the answer to how to upload file(.zip/.txt/ any other file format) from angular (4/5) to spring/rest controller. Writing down my learning below for those who looking same thing.:)

**Front-end coding ::**

## 1. HTML (eg. UploadFile.component.html):

```
<input type="file" formControlName="uploadFile" (change)="uploadFileToServer($event)"/>
```

## 2. Component (eg. UploadFile.component.ts) :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions, Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'file-uploader',
  templateUrl: './uploadFile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploadFile.component.css'],
})
export class FileUploadComponent {

public uploadFileToServer(event) {
  let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
  if (fileList.length > 0) {
    let file: File = fileList[0];
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
    formData.append('fileType', 'zip');
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post('domain/urservice', formData, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
      .subscribe(
      data => console.log('success'),
      error => console.log(error)
      )
  }
} 

}
```

(note - this server communication call should be present in some service not in component but for simplicity i am writing it in component)

**server-side coding ::**

## 1 .  Spring/Rest controller (FileUploadController.java) :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/urservice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();

    // directory to save file
    String tempDir = System.getProperty("jboss.server.temp.dir");

      MultipartFile file = request.getFile(itr.next());
      String fileType = request.getParameter("fileType");
      String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

      File dir = new File(tempDir);
      File fileToImport = null;
      if (dir.isDirectory()) {

        try {
            fileToImport = new File(dir + File.separator + fileName);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToImport));
            stream.write(file.getBytes());
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Got error in uploading file.");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Have a look here:
https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

So you can build a service which gets triggered when you press submit in a form, which attaches the file, whatever that is, a zip, img or whatever to the POST request.

2) In your template you can use something similar:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" accept=".zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

3) Have a look here to force the file extention:
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-attribute-selector/

Comment: Thanks , so helpful answer